# How to understand if a row has been queried by a select query previously?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

At my application there is a table and I am inserting new rows that table. There is a Java class that gets a row(by a select query) from that table and send it to web part. I want to get the latest row everytime (Ican handle it with getting the row that which has the biggest auto generated id) however I have to check that if I select a row and send it to web part and if there happens no insert when I come to select the latest row `I don't want to send any data to web part if that row has been send previously` (I mean if that row had retrieved by a select query)

I think that if I put a new column i.e. named as `has_sent` (that has a value of 0 by default) and if I select that row I can set it to 1 and before I send the data I can check that if that column is 0 or not.

I want to learn that is there any better way to handle that situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row doesn't remember if it has been requested or not, you'll have to use your `has_sent` column.